# Jasmine unit test factory

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new on Jasmine testing ,here I want to test my $resources in the Factory,
so I have first this factory :

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])
  .factory('API', function($rootScope, $resource) {
    var base = "http://192.168.178.40:8000/api";
    return {
      getGuestListForH: $resource(base + '/guests/:id/:wlist', {
        id: '@id',
        wlist: '@wlist'
      })
    }
  });
```

and my test :

```js
beforeEach(module('starter.services'));
describe('service: API resource', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var API = null;
  var $httpBackend = null;

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _API_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    API = _API_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.whenGET('http://192.168.178.40:8000/api/guests').respond([{
      id: 1,
      name: 'a'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'b'
    }]);
  }));
  afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });
  it('expect all resource in API to br defined', function() {
    $httpBackend.expect('http://192.168.178.40:8000/api/guests');

    var dd = API.getGuestListForH.query();
    expect(dd.length).toEqual(2);

    expect(API.getGuestListForH).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
});
```

and I got in the result :

- **Expected 0 to equal 2**

  - **Expected spy but got Function**
    What the wrong here .I want to test the resource in the factory what the best way to do that ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your tests can do even without `$rootScope`and all the other variable declarations you've done.

And since you're writing the tests for the Service's method, instead of `expect`ing it `toHaveBeenCalled`, you should call it and expect the results to be something.

Something like this:

```
describe('Service: starter.services', function() {
    beforeEach(module('starter.services'));
    describe('service: API resource', function() {
        beforeEach(inject(function(_API_, _$httpBackend_) {
            API = _API_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

            $httpBackend.whenGET('http://192.168.178.40:8000/api/guests').respond([{
                id: 1,
                name: 'a'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: 'b'
            }]);
        }));

        afterEach(function() {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('expect all resource in API to br defined', function() {
            var dd = API.getGuestListForH.query();
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(dd.length).toEqual(2);
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot  for reply , your solution work but if i delete by accident the params in the resource  ( id, wlist ) in the service module, this test will always return success and I think the purpose of testing to show like this errors. What you opinion ?